# Compactness of composition of operators

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness

Let $V$ be a Hilbert space with inner product $(\cdot, \cdot)_V$, and let $L:V \to V^*$ be defined by
$$\langle Lv_1,v_2 \rangle = (v_1, v_2)_V$$
i.e., $L$ generates the cannonical given inner product on $V$.

Let $T:V \to V$ be a (possibly nonlinear) continuous operator.

If $T$ is compact, so is $L \circ T$.

Is it possible for $L \circ T$ be compact without $T$ compact? Does anyone know any theorems guaranteeing such a compactness without assuming compactness for $T$?

Comment: Of course.  It isn't too hard to find an example of non-compact $L,T$ such that $L \circ T = 0$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Okay, let me change the question a bit

Comment: What's a "possibly non-linear operator"? Is that just a function from $V$ to $V$?  Does the function need to be continuous?

Comment: Also, your definition of $L$ is not making sense to me.   It seems as though $V$ already has an inner product $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$ , and you're defining a *new* bilinear form $(v_1,v_2)_V = \langle L v_1, v_2 \rangle$.  Do you mean to say that $L$ is a linear operator chosen such that this new bilinear form is an inner product?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom $T$ is a nonlinear operator which is continuous from $V$ to $V$. I edit. As for $L$, yes $V$ has an inner product already, and $L$ is simply the linear operator such that its bilinear form is the inner product.

Comment: What do you mean when you say its bilinear form is **the** inner product?  Do you mean that
$$
\langle Lv_1, v_2 \rangle = \langle v_1, v_2 \rangle?
$$
If not, then you should make it clear that you're talking about two different inner products on the same space.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. I have only defined one inner product on $V$.

Comment: Oh, now I see what you're getting at.  This is an unusual way to talk about inner products, but I guess that's fine.  Really, you mean something like
$$
\langle v_1,v_2 \rangle := [L(v_1)](v_2)
$$

Comment: What does it mean for a non-linear operator to be compact?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom it takes a bounded sequence into a sequence that has a convergent subsequence

Comment: My hunch is that $L \circ T$ is compact iff $T$ is compact.  After all, $L$ is effectively the identity map on $V$.